# Not able to delete data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have checked a lot of answers and also implemented their code for deleting the data from Firebase Database. But when I am clicking on delete button nothing is happening, data is not deleted. I am not able to understand why this issue is arising.

Here is my code:

```
    deletebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String subcategory = spinnersub.getSelectedItem().toString();
                spinnersub.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (parentcategory.equals("Jokes")) {
                            subCategoryQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Jokes").orderByChild("subcategory")
                                    .equalTo(subcategory);

                            subCategoryQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot subSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        subSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    Log.e("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else if(parentcategory.equals("Shayari")){
                            subCategoryQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Shayari").orderByChild("subcategory")
                                    .equalTo(subcategory);

                            subCategoryQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot subSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        subSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    Log.e("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Please tell what am I doing wrong? Why it is not working? Why data is not deleting?

Comment: removeValue may fail for many reasons, try adding CompletionListener for more info about what's going on

Comment: can you tell me how to implement CompletionListener???

Comment: can you confirm function is getting called correctly? ( Put log/breakpoints etc). Also make sure read/write rules are set correctly for object that you are trying to delete